# Flask SQLAlchemy - custom datetime JSON encoder

Tags: python, json, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this Menu model defined with a custom `JSON` `serialization()` function:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Menu(db.Model):
    __tablename__='menu'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False)  
    dishes = db.relationship('Dish',
                            back_populates='menu',
                            uselist=True)
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return 
                { 'id' : self.id,
                'created': self.created,
                'dishes' : [ item.serialize() for item in self.dishes]}
```

This works fine, except for 'created' attribute, dependent on `datetime`, which
throws the infamous `TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable` error.

Usually, this datetime error can be solved for the whole data dictionary by subclassing, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

and called like so:

```
json.dumps(yourobj, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
```

but I can't serialize all my models with `json.dumps()` because of my own `serialize()` in the model, and changing it would cause all sorts of problems.

So how do I combine and apply this datetime solution only for my `self.created` attribute above, without `json.dumps()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just modify `serialize()` to return `self.created.isoformat()`.

```
def serialize(self):
    """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
    return { 
        'id': self.id,
        'created': self.created.isoformat(),
        'dishes': [item.serialize() for item in self.dishes]
        }
```

Comment: This is a cop-out. Can't we register a custom json encoder like non-serial killers?